# USB thumb drive - why does file transfer speed vary so much?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

The thumb drive is FAT32. I often transfer files from the thumb drive to an internal HDD (Ext4).

1. Sometimes, the files are transferred at about 15MB/s.
2. Sometimes, the files are transferred at about 150MB/s.
3. Sometimes, I don't know what the transfer rate is but a 3GB file will take less than 10 sends to be transferred.

It seems to me that this speed difference is related to whether USB2 or USB3 protocol is being used at the time, although I don't know what the transfer rates are supposed to be for these protocols.

In any case, why would it vary? Is there any way that I can **always** achieve the higher rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things that could be the reason:

The transfer rate depends a lot on the file count/file size - more so on a filesystem like FAT32.

Are you sure the files were actually written completely when you measured the end time? I would guess the 3GB file was not yet finished writing, for example.

Possibly some files where in the buffer cache in the fast case.

Did you drop the cache before testing?
You can do it by `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: 1. Yes, the file transfer was complete. I understand this to be the case because (a) the file in the new location is the same size as the file was in the old location; and (b) the file is gone from the old location and is only seen in the new location; and (c) the File Operations dialog box progress bar has reached the end and the box has disappeared.

2. I don't know what you mean by "Did you drop the cache before testing?". If you mean that the file was, for example, already in the computer's cache, it seems unlikely to me. I start the file transfer immediately after moving the thumb drive.

Comment: Yes it seems like I have been doing some file operations sometimes before the transfer, which would explain why the file was (at least partially) in the cache.